# Two bodies rotation separation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

I am currently working on programing a small simulation involving two bodies, yet I find myself somewhat unconvinced by the results I'm obtaining.

Consider this particular test scenario: I have two identical masses connected by an inelastic cable. These masses are subjected to rotation induced by two forces acting on them within their respective body frames (imagine thrusters attached to the objects).

Initially, the masses possess no velocity, but due to the applied forces, they begin to rotate around the system's center of mass.

After a certain period of time, the cable breaks, releasing the masses to move independently. Upon breaking, the masses are ejected tangentially to the circular motion.

In my simulation, I observe a uniform linear motion as expected, but the two bodies also exhibit rotation around their axes. I have some trouble to explain that.

While I understand the principle of conservation of angular momentum, I had anticipated that the angular momentum would be entirely converted into linear motion.

What should I anticipate? Do the masses continue to rotate after the break?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the objects keep the same face towards the centre of rotation then each one revolves about its own axis once per rotation. The angular momentum from this motion must be conserved, so each object will continue to revolve about its own axis after the cable breaks.

Comment: Yes thanks it makes sense. Also watching hammer throwing at Olympics helps to visualize the phenomenon.